# Change some dataframe values to 0

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, coordinates

from a list of lists of coordinates such as:

```
coordinates = [((3,54), (6,23)...)((1,10)(2,98)]
```

I'm getting a dataframe with this code:

```
all_coordinates = [item for img in coordinates for item in img]
c = Counter(all_coordinates)
max_x = max([item[0] for item in all_coordinates])
max_y = max([item[1] for item in all_coordinates])
coordinates_dict = dict()
for i in range(max_x + 1):
    for j in range(max_y + 1):
        coordinates_dict.update({(i,j): c[(i,j)]})
df = pd.DataFrame(coordinates_dict.items(), columns=['Coordinates','Value'])
pd.set_option("display.max_rows", 20, "display.max_columns", 20)
df[["x", "y"]] = pd.DataFrame(df.Coordinates.to_list())
```

That gives me a dataframe like:

[image: Dataframe]

I would like to know How can I turn into 0 all values from a selected list of coordiantes:

All coordinates from the following list, turn in the dataframe into 0:

```
coords_0 = [(29, 131), (29, 132), (29, 133), (30, 129), (30, 130), (30, 133), (31, 127)...]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df['Value'] = df.apply(lambda x: 0 if x['Coordinates'] in coords_0 else x['Value'], axis=1)`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm getting an invalid syntax error, do you know how can I solve this? I have to put this in my code in the end? Thanks!

Comment: See if this works for you now @JoanCarlesMonteroJiménez